# How to update time to NOW()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to set a `date` field to `NOW()` if it's outdated. Here is the query I'm trying to run without success:

```php
Quiz::('date', '<', DB::raw('NOW()'))->update(['date' => DB::raw('NOW()')])
```

How do I fix it?

P.S
I don't want to deal with `Carbon`, if possible, to avoid the server/DB time difference issues.

Comment: First of all, your update() syntax seems to be wrong, it should be: ->update(['date' => DB::raw('NOW()')])

Comment: @DenisMysenko Fixed it

Answer (score 5):

Try something like:

```
DB::table('quizzes')->where(DB::raw('date < NOW()'))->update(['date' => DB::raw('NOW()')]);
```

Comment: The where clause seems to be incorrect, can't get it to work

Comment: I noticed when debugging the query, that `is null` is appended to the generated MySQL query: `. . . where date < NOW() is null`. Why is this happening?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611461/selecting-entries-whose-date-field-now/37611759#37611759, the `where` clause should be replaced with `whereRaw`, to avoid the `is null` issue