# Selecting entries whose `date_field < NOW()`

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

When I try to run the following query, it returns nothing:

```php
Item::where(\DB::raw('date_field < NOW()'))->get()
```

The reason for this is, that `is null` is appended to the generated MySQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM items WHERE date_field < NOW() is null;
```

Why does the `is null` part get appended to the above query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in Laravel and has been reported on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1591).  Use `whereRaw()` instead and pass a string:

```
Item::whereRaw('date_field < NOW()')->get()
```

Comment: @AlexanderLomia This is by far the best answer in the thread of the current four. Use this one.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for an informative answer!

Answer (score 1):

No idea why the `not null` part gets appended. But I found a workaround.
Try this

```
Item::whereNotNull(\DB::raw('date_field < NOW()'))->get()
```

Of course, you may use built-in features like `Carbon`

```
Item::where('date_field', '<', Carbon\Carbon::now())->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I would like to avoid using `Carbon::now()` to avoid the server / DB time incompatibility issues. Your workaround works well, though

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way..

```
Item::where('date_field','<','NOW()')->get()
```

Comment: That does not work. Laravel requires raw queries for MySQL functions.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM items WHERE date_field < GETDATE();